# Mudar formato de campo em excel para importar no wizard do sql server

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-excel, importação

Estou precisando fazer uma importação de dados de um excel para o sql server.

Meu grande problema é que os dados que vem da origem, de uma coluna do excel está sendo interpretado por esse wizard como varchar, mesmo eu fazendo todas as mudanças que eu consigo imaginar.

Basicamente eu tentei:

- No excel mudar o tipo dos dados (colocar como moeda)(coloca como geral)
- No excel, copiar os dados, colocar em arquivo de texto, mudar o tipo
  de dados depois colar no excel. (coloca como moeda)(coloca como geral)

De ambas as formas o wizard interpreta que ele é do tipo varchar

Como mudar isso?

Comment: É possível que um dado esteja em um formato incorreto? Uma `alternativa` de solução: Importe os dados em uma tabela temporaria, depois faça um insert com select na tabela correta, corrigindo os tipos(se tiver um dado errado vai da erro na conversão e você vai identificar)

Comment: Não está, a planilha está certinha

Comment: Mas boa ideia, valeu